# How to make multiple ranges in a array in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking for a single vector with values [(0:400) (-400:-1)]

Can anyone help me on how to write this in python.

Answer (score 0):

Using Numpy `.array` to create the vector and `.arange` to generate the range:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[np.arange(401)], [np.arange(-400, 0)]], dtype=object)
```